# Chronicle queue file corrupted?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

When I read message from a chronicle queue, I got an exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Meta data not ready c0000000". Is is possible to repair this queue file?

Answer (score 0):

This error could occur if you are reading using a much older version of the queue library. Can you try the latest version 4.5.13?

Note this would be a bug in the reading code rather than a corruption of the file. You can use DumpQueueMain to check this.